# get values from sql rows with same name but different values

Tags: sql

i need help concerning a sql query. first of all, i have a database with the following structure (example):

> ID              NAME              VALUE
>   123           ABC_A            Text Text Text  
>   123           ABC_A            Some more Text  
>   123           ABC_A            Even more Text 
>   123           ABC_B            some other text

now, i want to get all the different values of rows with the name "ABC_A". i tried to get those via group by and having, without success.

Comment: what is the result (*literally*) of your desired query? `Text Text Text`, `Some more Text ` and `some other text`?

Comment: it should be "text text text", "some more text" and "Even more text"

Comment: then i guess it should be easy enough, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IS this what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Value
FROM tableName
WHERE ID = 123 AND Name = 'ABC_A'
```

but if the value of the *ID and Name are unique* then you can *omit* `distinct` (*to avoid overkilling the server*)

```
SELECT Value
FROM tableName
WHERE ID = 123 AND Name = 'ABC_A'
```

Answer (score 2):

> i want to get all the different values of rows with the name "ABC_A"

This would be for example:

```
SELECT value, count(value) FROM tbl WHERE name = 'ABC_A' GROUP BY value;
```

If you do not need the count of times one value appears, remove it, or use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT value FROM tbl WHERE name = 'ABC_A';
```

If you want the different values of rows by ID also,

```
SELECT value, count(value)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE id = 123 AND name = 'ABC_A'
    GROUP BY value;
```

Or if you want "ALL" the different values (with duplicates too) remove the `GROUP BY` (and you no longer can use the `count()`, which would be always 1):

```
SELECT value FROM tbl WHERE id = 123 AND name = 'ABC_A';
```

Answer (score 2):

Additional to John, if you use the keyword Distinct you onle get DIFFERENT Values, therefore

```
SELECT DISTINCT Value
FROM tableName
WHERE ID = 123 AND
        Name = 'ABC_A'
```

Answer (score 2):

The `GROUP BY` statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.
In above case why dont you use simple where clause

```
select * from <tableName> where name ='ABC_A'
```

Comment: That would be all right if he wanted "all" values; but if he wanted each value only once, no duplicates, then either GROUP or DISTINCT are needed.